# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop un-attended installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, automation

I want to install ubuntu18.04 Desktop  LTS .  How can I perform auto installation with ks.cfg file or preseed file. ?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please specify what have you tried so far and the contents of your seed files? Have you followed any manuals and documentation for this process? Please edit your question and add some information so we can help.

Comment: I am commenting this since `ks.cfg` sounds familiar (I think it's debian's example file from a documented tutorial): Ubuntu desktop installs itself a bit differently than the server installation (though server installation changed dramatically on version 18.04, and both changed in version 20.04). It will not work for your desktop iso, and overall desktop installations are very limited when it comes to preseeding.